# Read data's from csv and form JSON Array and then POST -JMETER 4.0

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell, jmeter-4.0, jsr223

URL looks like this :
https://url1/url2/url3

Post Body Data JSON Format:

```
Test:{
test1,
test2,
test3
}
```

I have to read the data from CSV ,pass Url values and corresponding test1, test2 ,etc data in random nos..

Eg: in one hit test 1,test2 should be posted.

In other hit test1,test2,test3,test4 should be posted.

In other hit test1, test4 should be posted.

In other hit test1,test2,test3,test4,test5 should be posted.

My CSV looks like this

```
Url1 url2 url3 test1

Url1 url2 url3 test2

Url1 url2 url3 test3

Url1 url2 url3 test4

Url1 url2 url3 test5

Url7 url8 url9 test11

Url7 url8 url9 test12

Url7 url8 url9 test13

Url7 url8 url9 test14
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/random-csv-data-set/RandomCSVDataSetConfig.md) instead. You can download it by using [Plugin Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/).

> Random CSV Data Set Config is used to read CSV rows from file, split and put them into JMeter variables in random order.

Just check the Random Order field like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.this is for generation of data's randomly ..But how do I get Array of data say 2 in one hit, 3 in second hit, 5 in third hit

Comment: CSV Data Set Config read only one line at a time whatever it is random order or not!